# not able to invoke FERN DescriptorMatcher in opencv

Tags: opencv, surf, object-detection

In my Maverick OSX 10.9, I am using a custom built opencv-2.4.8 SDK, with  some minor changes from the default cmake options.

The minor changes are. (I don't think these changes are pertinent to the question here)

```
OCV_OPTION(WITH_GTK   OFF)
OCV_OPTION(WITH_OPENGL ON)
OCV_OPTION(WITH_QT ON)
```

When I try to do matching of SURF keypoints with the FERN matcher, the following step does not work. The system is not able to create such a matcher.

```
Ptr<GenericDescriptorMatcher> descriptorMatcher = GenericDescriptorMatcher::create("FERN", "fern_params.xml");
```

Additionally, if I try to invoke the debug-compiled sample program, I get the following error response.

```
./bin/cpp-example-generic_descriptor_match ../data/frame1.jpg ../data/frame2.jpg FERN fern_params.xml
```

gives 
    "Cannot create descriptor"

Comment: Did you solve your problem?